# bootbox confirm change behaviour on pressing enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

I have a bootbox confirm popup for confirmation before an action.
Somehow the action is delicate and no key press should confirm the popup.

Success should only be done by clicking OK button, also I dont want to change the behaviour of ESC closing the dialog.

It would be better if I could do this without having a key listener.

Existing bootbox :

```
bootbox.confirm("<center>Are you sure you want to do the operation", 
     function (result) {

                //Do something
                });
```

Comment: `$('*').off('keyup keydown keypress');` try it before opening bootbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootbox events -

```
bootbox.on("show.bs.modal") //prevent actions here

bootbox.on("hidden.bs.modal") //resume whenever its hidden.
```

You can prevent all events on opening box as

```
    var d = bootbox.confirm("msg", function(result) {
        if (result)
            callback_success();
        else
            callback_cancel();
    });

    d.on("show.bs.modal", function() {

        $('*').off('keyup keydown keypress'); // disable it on show bootbox
    });

    d.on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {

        $('*').on('keyup keydown keypress'); // call it on hidden bootbox
    });
```

or this is enough in your case -

```
 d.on("show.bs.modal", function() {
        $(this).find('#modalButton').off('keyup keydown keypress'); // disable it on show bootbox
     });
```

Now you don't need `hidden.bs.modal` event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is also blocking ESC from closing the dialog.
Is there any way where enter button can also close the dialog ?

Comment: @MihirKhadilkar, see the edited or snip above. You can target the ok button itself.